# Testing on Android device without wireless contract like AT&T or Verizon etc

Tags: android, testing, device, handheld

For testing apps on an android device, is it possible to test on a phone that isn't connected to a data network like 3G or Edge? Basically, I want to test the app, but I dont want to buy another line to test on the phone. The emulator is too cumbersome to work with. Also, if that is possible, can I still connect to wifi? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good luck buying a used, off-contract T-Mobile phone (mytouch) for testing lower-end performance. I use it with a pay-as-you-go T-Mobile SIM card, no data plan, with no problem.

Comment: We ended up buying a pay-as-you-go phone. I'll be testing it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's possible. WiFi is available on virtually all phones.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use wifi without a data contract -- there are tablets out that are "wifi-only".  You could also just tether the phone to your PC and get connectivity that way.

The Android emulator that comes with the SDK definitely does not have any actual 3G data connectivity, and it works fine.

Comment: well its very slow. I have a pretty good PC and it can hardly play back video

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

But some phones sold through carriers require substantial effort to initially get operational if they aren't on a service plan to run through the carrier's setup wizard.

Google the specific model you are interested in in conjunction with "no sim" or "no service plan" in order to research other's difficulties and potential solutions for that.